# Chrome, css filter blur and scale at children and overflow hidden on parent results glowing edges

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

Parent div has `overflow:hidden`, and the child element is *scaled* and *blured* on `:hover`, *with transition*. While animated you can see *glowing edges* ( I use `transform:scale()` strictly to avoid this, but it gets worse). 
*I am using Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m*.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t5dyn9e/)

```
<div class="overflow">
    <div class="inner">
        Hover
    </div>
</div>

.overflow{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    transform: scale(1);
    filter: blur(0px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overflow:hover .inner{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but we should rather find a way to force the WHOLE .inner element to be blurred.

Right now it seems like the browser only blurs the visible part of the element, i.e. after it was clipped by the parent.

The flickering seems to be the transition between the animating frames using a fast interpolation and the last frame using a better rendering.

http://jsfiddle.net/5wz9w8o0/

Comment: You only encounter this kind of bug once a year!

Answer (score 3):

it chrome BUG with scale and overflow .

for the container that have the ( overflow:hidden )
add

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: Can you refer/link to the chrome bug that you're mentioning that is actually related directly to this?

Answer (score 1):

The glowing edges is due to the green background being blurred -- creates a sort of faded edge effect. you can solve this by moving your `background: green` style to the `.overflow` DIV. Also the scale transforms seem unnecessary now.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3t5dyn9e/2/)**

```
.overflow{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
}
.inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.inner:hover{
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If your content is HTML (not solid color background) that adds a bit of complexity. I kept running into an issue where the blur was applied to the visible area during the transition then the blur applied to the whole image once the transition ended... strange behavior but as far as I can tell unavoidable. I was able to achieve the desired effect by stacking two objects and using background images setting up two objects with the `.back` object already having the blur effect applied. Any text or other elements can be placed directly within the `.front` DIV but full size images need to be applied using CSS `background-image: url()` and must be 20 pixels larger than the container to account of the faded 10px blur effect on the edges. Hope this helps you out.

**[New JSFiddle example using image](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3t5dyn9e/3/)**

```
<div class="overflow">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="front">Hover</div>
</div>

.overflow {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url(http://cache.graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/2982/SITours/tampa-bay-downtown-and-manatee-river-helicopter-tour-in-tampa-109952.jpg);
    background-size: 220px 220px;
    background-position: center center;
}
.front {
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.back {
    z-index: 50;
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
.front:hover {
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

**[Alternate New JSfiddle example using HTML elements](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3t5dyn9e/4/)**

Comment: But this isn't a solution if the .inner div is html content or image, wich is in my case. This is just simplified version of the issue. Works fine on Firefox.

Comment: @MilosR - I addressed your issue and appear to have found a solution... take a look at the edited answer above.

Comment: That's the problem, as far as i know only in Chrome, when transition ends it look's like it recreate blur effect, but only if parent has overflow:hidden, thanks for this solution, i will try this.

Comment: appending rules transform: translateZ(0); or -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  to .inner fixes the problem while transition acts, but glowing edge now remains at the enf of transition... Looks [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343568) issue is connected to our problem.